# Deployment issue of Jsf webapp on websphere v9.0

Tags: jsf-2

I am writing a project in RAD 9.6.1 with UI being developed in  JSF 2.0. When I try to deploy my app on Websphere 9.0 I am getting the below error. I tried doing a Google but could not get any solution out of this tried all possible suggestions. the solutions I tried to get this fixed. I am deploying the app as an ear under which I have the war configured.
it works with Tomcat and jboss fine.

getting null pointer exception from the following line in component

```
static {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ValueExpression vex = facesContext.getApplication()
            .getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(
                    facesContext.getELContext(), "#{GenericDAO}",
                    ICRUDDAO.class); //this line give null pointer exception at initialization
    dao = (ICRUDDAO) vex.getValue(facesContext.getELContext());
}
```

Comment: I did not use the WebSphere but I noted it has guide lin, [look it](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tweb_jsf22.html) perhaps it resolves your problem

Comment: A static code block is processed as soon as a ClassLoader loads your class. This does not necessarily happen during JSF-Servlet request processing. Therefore it's unlikely that your facesContext variable is different from `null`.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem adding shared library of mojarra jsf implemention the server suppourt myfaces only  Here's [a link]
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/devTips/entry/Using_a_Custom_JSF_implementation_with_WebSphere_Liberty_Profile?lang=en

Comment: Why was using the built-in myfaces failing? The NPE seems to be in your code, so this is a very strange  solution...

Comment: The implementation of jsf project Depend on mojarra not my faces so it was failing to initialize that's why i got NPE .

Comment: Then see if you really need the mojarra calls and if not remove them. Very, very rarely you need this. Most likely it was done by accident